# Why does this code exhaust the connection pool so quickly?

Tags: c#, multithreading, ado.net, sqlconnection

I'm trying to test my connection to a Sql Server database using the code below. All it does it try to open the connection in a background task, with a 5 second timeout:

```cs
private bool CanConnect()
{
    //we'll give it 5 seconds to connect
    var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    var connectSuccess = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
          //the connection
          using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
          {
             connection.Open();
          }
        }
        catch { }
    }).Wait(timeout);

    //return status
    return connectSuccess;
}
```

But when I do this, I very quickly get the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Timeout expired.  The timeout
>   period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This
>   may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max
>   pool size was reached.'

This always happens on the 4th connection attempt, which is puzzling because the default pool size is 100.

But I don't get why it happens at all, since I'm disposing of the connection with the `using` block. So why would I not have an available connection, and so quickly?

Comment: Can you give us your connection string( ofc without showing credentials)

Comment: The code you provided doesn't prove that: 1) it happens on 4th connection; 2) default value of max connection in the pool isn't redefined by connection string and 3) the connections are returned to the pool before the moment when another connection is requested.

Answer (score 0):

Connections that are used from the Connection pool are only returned to the pool upon being Garbage Collected.

But I cannot understand (from the code I am seeing) why you would exhaust your pool.  Why aren't you using the DB connection timeout?

Comment: Because of the considerations discussed [here](https://improve.dk/controlling-sqlconnection-timeouts). Regardless of the ConnectionTimeout setting, it can take quite a while to fail, and I want to fail much faster.

Comment: this leads to other issues, perhaps a network issue that gets resolved... I personally think this is overkill.

Comment: No, connection is lost after ending of using scope when triggering Dispose method on IDisposable. Garbage collector doesnt call Dispose method and leaves connection open. OP is using 'using' so connection is closed, i guess there is some other networking problem in his environment